# Microsoft Access Print preview report subreport getting cut off?

Tags: microsoft-access

While creating and previewing a report on Microsoft Access, the last field of the sub report is being cut off. There is a scroll bar if viewed as report view. Everything has been set to can grow. If I dragged longer toward the right, half of the field will be showed on another page.
[image: Print Preview Report]

What should I set to get all the contents to be printed on one page? The sub report contains about 40 fields.

Comment: Either squash the controls up together or print landscape. Can Grow is for vertical stretching when a control contains different amounts of data.

Comment: @Remou What do you mean by squash the controls? The orientation is already set to landscape.